# Can't Scroll to Top with UITableView's estimatedRowHeight and reloadData()

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a UITableView with dynamic cells that I set with the following code:

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 158
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

If I scroll to the middle of the table view and call this code to scroll back to the top:

```
tableView.setContentOffset(CGPointZero, animated:true)
```

it works as expected.  However, if I scroll to the middle of the table view, call `tableView.reloadData()`, and then call that same code above to scroll back to the top, it's wildly off. In fact, it triggers the refresh control animation because it sets the content offset of the table view at a point much higher than it should, because `reloadData` set the content offset Y value to a much higher number, even though I didn't scroll.  Is this a bug or is there a workaround?

Using iOS 9, Swift 2.0.

Comment: Are you calling `reloadData` then immediately calling `setContentOffset` before returning to the runloop? If so you probably want to schedule the setContentOffset to run from the run loop. That way reloadData will finish then your offset will run.

Comment: No, `reloadData` is actually called well before the setContentOffset. It definitely finishes.